# How do I specify a dependency that end with '<version>-bin.exe' in gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How do I get
**winsw-1.19-bin.exe** from the repo below:

```groovy
repositories {
    maven { 
        url 'http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile('com.sun.winsw:winsw:1.19@exe')
}
```

The above returns:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find winsw.exe (com.sun.winsw:winsw:1.19).
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/com/sun/winsw/winsw/1.19/winsw-1.19.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I was missing the classifier

```
compile('com.sun.winsw:winsw:1.19:bin@exe')
```

or

```
compile(group: 'com.sun.winsw', name: 'winsw', version: '1.19', classifier: 'bin', ext: 'exe')
```

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: My fault, it is probably because the question is only a couple of hours old right now.